# Why does file_get_contents work with google.com but not with my site?

Tags: php, django, get

```
$page1 = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$page2 = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8000/prueba');
```

When I echo the results, with Google it works but not with my site. And when I put the address on the explorer works. And this happen with all the site that i make in django. :(

Warning: file_get_contents(`http://localhost:8000/prueba`) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\squirrelmail\plugins\captcha\backends\b2evo\b2evo.php on line 138

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\squirrelmail\plugins\captcha\backends\b2evo\b2evo.php on line 138

Comment: What does it retrieve? An empty string? What does `var_dump(get_headers('http://localhost:8000/prueba'));` give?

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\squirrelmail\plugins\captcha\backends\b2evo\b2evo.php on line 138  well the execution time was too long,  do you want to fetch the content of the index(.html/.php) file or the directory prueba?

Comment: does manually going to http://localhost:8000/prueba actually work? And are you using a local test system? If your doing this on an external server it won't work

Comment: You **shouldn't be using this function** to do this anyway.

Comment: i really make is a request in php to my site in Django. i whant fetch the site that i make in django, and the directory prueba doesn exist, because django its different that php

Comment: yes, if i do manually going to localhost:8000/prueba works, the fact is that the function file_get_contents dont works with none site that i make in django

Comment: when i put var_dump(get_headers('http://localhost:8000/prueba'));  the answer is arning: get_headers(http://localhost:8000/prueba) [function.get-headers]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\servicio\index.php on line 9

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\servicio\index.php on line 9

Answer (score 27):

For anyone having this problem using PHP Built-in web server (with Laravel in my case), it is caused by your request being blocked by file_get_contents() / curl functions.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) of dev server say that

> PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.

Since the PHP built-in server is single threaded, requesting another url on your server
will halt first request and it gets timed out.

As a solution, you can use proper web server (nginx, apache etc.).

**Edit:** As of now, I really suggest you to use [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sail) as a development environment for PHP projects. It saves you lots of time with setup and configuration of different services (webserver, databases, queues, etc.).

Comment: The last 2 hours of a 24hour hackathon - wasted by this nonsense!  At least I know now! :)

Answer (score 4):

As zub0r [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651196/5816097), the built-in PHP server is single threaded. If you do not want to install and configure a web server like nginx, and do not want to use Homestead or Valet, there is another easy solution:

Start another instance of your build-in PHP server with another port and use this in the internal requests of your app.

```
php -S localhost:8000
\\ in another console
php -S localhost:8001
```

I use this in my Laravel app when I request some local dummy API via Guzzle and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get **the result** of a content from a PHP local file, you can use:

`exec('php file.php', $content);`

Sometimes the $content variable is an array, so just point to the correct key, like $content[3]

Hope this helps you.