# laravel passport oauth function using curl or guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, laravel-passport

I have this route in api route file

```
Route::post('/user/register', 'HomeController@register');
```

and the register function is

```
public function register(Request $request)
 {
    $user = User::create([
        ...
    ]);
    return $this->getAccessToken($request);
}

public function getAccessToken(Request $request)
{
    $url = url('/oauth/token');
    $headers = ['Accept' => 'application/json'];
    $http = new Client;

    $response = $http->post($url, [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'my_client_id',
            'client_secret' => 'my_client_secret',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password'
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);
}
```

now when I send post request to the url the user is created but the request keep loading and no response and the whole application is hanging until I close the IDE - phpstorm - 
I send the same parameters to the same url `/oauth/token` from postman and it works fine.
any help or any one tell me what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the **curl** do not work when the url contains port like

localhost:8000

Comment: but if you send the request without port number it gives me  "The requested URL /api/v1/auth/login was not found on this server."

Answer (score 1):

See this question on Stack Overflow:

[Why does file_get_contents work with google.com but not with my site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014958/why-does-file-get-contents-work-with-google-com-but-not-with-my-site/25651196#25651196)

> For anyone having this problem using PHP Built-in web server (with
>   Laravel in my case), it is caused by your request being blocked by
>   file_get_contents() / curl functions.
>
> Docs of dev server say that
>
> ```
> PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.
> ```
>
> Since the PHP built-in server is single threaded, requesting another
>   url on your server will halt first request and it gets timed out.
>
> As a solution, you can use nginx (LEMP stack) or other web servers.
>
> Edit: As of now, I really suggest you to use Homestead as development
>   environment for PHP projects. It saves you lots of work with
>   configuration, creation of virtual hosts and DB configuration for more
>   projects.