# Laravel: Solution for using custom Passport sign in with Guzzle

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am trying to do a route **/api/user/signin** and inside of controller to make a Guzzle HTTP post to **/oauth/token**. Great but the server stall. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350397/5796307

So how I should do? How to call /oauth/token without a HTTP request? I can "create" a request class and pass to that function?

Comment: You could start by posting your controller code, and possible your route.

Comment: @Adam you read my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use Guzzle or file_get_contents, create a new HTTP request from within the controller function and route it through the framework:

```
public function signin (Request $request) {

    // get an appropriate client for the auth flow
    $client = Client::where([
        'password_client' => true,
        'revoked'         => false
    ])->first();

    // make an internal request to the passport server
    $tokenRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'post', [
            'grant_type'    => 'password',
            'client_id'     => $client->id,
            'client_secret' => $client->secret,
            'username'      => $request->input('email'),
            'password'      => $request->input('password')
    ]);

    // let the framework handle the request
    $response = app()->handle($tokenRequest);

    // get the token from the response if authenticated, other wise redirect to login
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I love you!