# mPDF images generated by PHP scripts

Tags: php, pdf, composer-php, mpdf

I'm trying to generate images using PHP scripts and place them into a PDF file generated by the mPDF library.

I cloned the `mpdf-examples` repository which contains several examples, including one that has images, the link is https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf-examples so you can see the source code.

In `example04_images.php`, the images returned by `tiger.php` don't work.

When executing from the command line `php example04_images.php > out.pdf`, the file will contain `[X]` type of images, meaning that they failed to load.

When loading the script from the browser, it will get stuck forever loading.

My composer file is

```
{
    "name": "mpdf/examples",
    "description": "Example repository for Mpdf HTML to PDF generator",
    "require": {
    "ext-gd": "*",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "7.0.0-beta2"
    }
}
```

When I remove the bit of code that uses `.php` generated images, the PDF is generated correctly. It only fails when I include those php generated images.

My `php -v` is:

`PHP 7.0.24-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2017 16:33:02) ( NTS )`

It seems that using PHP generated images works for many people, and even the documentation says it's possible. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What server are you using for displaying the example in the browser?

Comment: I'm using PHP Cli. Should I switch to something else? If so, why does php cli fail at this? This also fails on Heroku

Comment: You mean you run the PHP embedded server `php -S`? What is the environment on Heroku?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `php -S`, and for Heroku I'm not sure but I see a `heroku-php-apache2` text there in the app configuration page.

Answer (score 0):

mPDF internally fetches images with a `file_get_contents` call. When using a single threaded server such as `php -S`, the subsequent request stalls the application. [This SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014958/why-does-file-get-contents-work-with-google-com-but-not-with-my-site/25651196#25651196) summarizes this behaviour neatly. This is why browser request hangs indefinitely.

mPDF can accomplish some of its capabilities on single threaded servers, but not all of them. A proper server (Apache, nginx with PHP-FPM) is greatly recommended.

It makes sense the images are not loaded correctly when running the script from the command line. Paths to the images are relative URLs which must be processed by PHP to return correct content. There is no simple way to achieve it without a subsequent HTTP request - which is beyond a scope of a simple php cli call.

To make the example work in the CLI, you would have to link to real image files (which I believe work correctly in the image example) or to provide a full URL to the tiger.php script where the script would be processed with a server.