# Passport Authedication Error in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, guzzle

```
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! [file] /var/www/html/local/api-sample-application/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php [line] 324
```

I'm getting this error when try to implement laravel passport authentication.

This is my code in routes/web.php content:

```
Route::get('/redirect', function () {
$query = http_build_query([
    'client_id'     => '3',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/callback',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope'         => '',
]);

return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
```

});
Route::get('/oauth/callback', function () {

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

if (request('code')) {
    $response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id'     => '3',
            'client_secret' => 'H1UQCKVRARwASEJLR4ugGjBHHvFy34SCzSJFqQLL',
            'redirect_uri'  => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/callback',
            'code'          => request('code'),
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), TRUE);
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => request('error')]);
}
```

});

When i hit this [URL](http://127.0.0.1:8000/redirect), i'm getting this error, not able to generate the token.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7FHG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after 1 day I found the reason...

Since the PHP built-in server is single threaded, requesting another url on your server will halt first request and it gets timed out.

So you can't request localhost from localhost in same thread.

You can easy check it, try 'get' come public server host, 'http://www.example-host.com'..

Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25651196/916682